# CMake does not find dbus-1

Tags: cmake, dbus

Hi im trying to get CMake to find dbus-1

I keep getting this error when i try to compile

```
--   Checking for module 'dbus-1'
--   No package 'dbus-1' found
```

Ive tried this command

```
pkg-config --cflags dbus-glib-1
```

I get the output

```
-I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib64/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include
```

I edited the CMakeLists.txt and added

```
include_directories(/usr/include/dbus-1.0/)
```

What  am i doing wrong??

Comment: In the shell, you run `pkg-config` for package `dbus-glib-1`. But the error message is about `dbus-1` package.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to know about CMake in this situation is don't use the `include_directories` to include any system directories with a hard-coded path(which is what you are doing now).  What you should do instead is use the CMake `FindPkgConfig` module which will call pkg-config and get those include directories for you.

To do this, something like the following should work.

```
include( FindPkgConfig )
pkg_check_modules( dbus REQUIRED dbus-1 )

# Add the include directories to our target executable/shared object.
# In this case, our target is called 'executable' and must have been
# created by a previous call to either 'add_executable' or 'add_library'
target_include_directories( executable PUBLIC ${dbus_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
```